# How set icon on install exe file?

Tags: windows, nsis

I should make package windows program, so I use NSIS for it.

I want to set icon under image. For example notepad ++.

Give me answer please, how to do it.

I can't find this problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6thBW.jpg)

Comment: Please click "enter image description here" for seeing image.

Comment: I don't see any relation between what seems to be your problem and the image. It probably helps to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first, then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

@user2491067,

First, include MUI2.nsh in your .nsi script:

```
!include "MUI2.nsh"
```

Then, include the path to your icon in your script:

```
!define MUI_ICON path_to_icon_file.ico
```

Comment: NSIS has a default icon, this just changes it but does not explain why there is no icon in the screen shot.

Comment: I believe the user was using the Notepad++ window as an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Modern UI (MUI[2].nsh) then you need to set the correct define: `!define MUI_ICON "c:\path\myicon.ico"` and if you are not using MUI then you can just set the icon attribute: `Icon "c:\path\myicon.ico"` and this will assign a icon to your installer executable.

This icon will be displayed in Explorer etc. but it will **not** be displayed in the UAC consent dialog unless you [sign](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/03/22/everything-you-need-to-know-about-authenticode-code-signing/) your installer with a certificate trusted by Windows.